# Using tidyr package in R, are we able to filter and extract links from a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyr

Let's say I have this in my tibble,

```
Transcript                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
1 Hi i would like to find out more about <a href="https://mywebsite.com/internalfaq/faq/154200">http://mywebsite.com/internalfaq/faq/154200</a> please help
2 Hello my results were withheld at <a href="https://mywebsite.com/123">https://mywebsite.com/123</a> hope you can help
3 Hello my friend join me at https://mywebsite.com/456
```

I tried

```
links = data %>%
    extract(Transcript, url.pattern)
```

but it's not giving me what I want. It's not returning me the list of links even though I supply the url pattern. It returns me the first word only. Is there something wrong here that I did? 
Thanks in advance!

This is my url pattern: `https://mywebsite.com/.*`

Comment: There do not appear to be any links in your example data, so your expected result is unclear.

Comment: right! added more info

Answer (score 2):

The `into` input to `extract` must be specified. Also, try adding parentheses to your regex.

```
url.pattern <- "(https://mywebsite.com/[^> | ]*)"
data %>%
  extract(Transcript, into = 'link',regex = url.pattern)
```

Comment: Wow cool! It works. Thanks! But looks like something wrong with my regex. The link will always be in this form https://mywebsite.com/12345, https://mywebsite.com/54321, but my current regex is giving me <a href="https://mywebsite.com/12345">https://mywebsite.com/12345</a> blah blah blah. It doesn't give me just the link itself though?

Comment: Your example appeared to change since I answered. Anyway - a slight change to the regrex to find ''https://mywebsite.com/" then continue until you hit a '>' should work if you have html format. The edited url.pattern should continue until either '>' or a space...in case another line has the url as in row 3 in the middle of the string and not at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `regmatches`

```
 regmatches(h,gregexpr("http.*?(\\d+)",h))
[[1]]
[1] "https://mywebsite.com/internalfaq/faq/154200" "http://mywebsite.com/internalfaq/faq/154200" 

[[2]]
[1] "https://mywebsite.com/123" "https://mywebsite.com/123"

[[3]]
[1] "https://mywebsite.com/456"
```

This gives you the whole url's. What is `h`? his the `Transcript[,1]`. It is a `vector` and not a `dataframe`.

Since it seems the webpages are repeated, you can obtaine only the first one in every vector by using `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr`:

```
regmatches(h,regexpr("http.*?(\\d+)",h))
[1] "https://mywebsite.com/internalfaq/faq/154200" "https://mywebsite.com/123"                   
[3] "https://mywebsite.com/456"
```

You can also use the `sub` function with a backreference:

```
sub("(.*:)(.*\\d+)(.*)","https:\\2",h)
[1] "https://mywebsite.com/internalfaq/faq/154200" "https://mywebsite.com/123"                   
[3] "https://mywebsite.com/456"
```